# Is it possible to resume downloading file from a different url?

Tags: windows, download-manager

Are there software tools specifically for ms windows such as file downloaders that can be used for downloading partially downloaded file when url of downloaded file changes?

Comment: I think one of the problems with this is that often there might be tiny changes in the two files. For this to have even a chance of working, both files would have to be exactly the same (same checksum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Pretty much any half decent download manager has this feature.

I have done this with [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/)

Comment: s/descent/decent/

Comment: and it's actually free

Comment: @Pavium +1 - Thanks... Technical knowledge is my strong point, not spelling!

Answer (score 2):

I have not actually tried this but I suppose if [**`wget`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html) is used with the '[**`-c`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Download-Options.html)' option to continue on a download of the exact-same (say, matching md5sum) file from a different URL, it would continue from an incompletely downloaded file.

Caveats:

- It is assumed that at least the second server in the above case supports continued download.
- If the file in question appears to be different at this second server,
  various things can happen (look at the '`-c`' options detail at the link).

Answer (score 1):

I think [GetRight](http://www.headlightsw.com/) will do this.  It will automatically search for mirrors, check the size and name of the file, and download from multiple sources.  I think you can just add your new file as a source manually and it should do what you want.  This program used to be free, I think it still is but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is a paid software